# OneWire arduino library with late definition of pin

Tags: c++, pointers, arduino

I have a need to use the OneWire library (with DallasTemperature library) in a context where I will not know the gpio pin used by library at compile time.  In all of the examples of this library, the pin is hard-coded.  I have tried to use pointers to workaround this, but my test code (below) doesn't work.

```
OneWire * oneWire; 
DallasTemperature * sensors;

void setup(void) {
    oneWire = &OneWire( 2 );
    sensors = &DallasTemperature( oneWire );


    sensors->begin(); 
}
```

Loop body omitted but uses similar dereferencing calls on sensors object as in setup().  My example code is using a hard-coded 2 in this test, but the production code will pull that value dynamically within the setup().

What am I doing wrong here?  Or is this simply not possible?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. you can use any pin number and you can contruct that object at any time? just replace that 2 by a function call

Comment: Apologies for not being clear.  The use of pointers in my example does NOT work.  And for the OneWire object to be available in both the setup and loop functions, it has to be declared globally.  I can't find a way to declare the object without knowing the pin number - which I won't know until inside the setup() function.

Answer (score 2):

You can Setup a oneWire instance with a "dummy" pin value (ex: Pin=13).

At runtime, in setup(), change it to a different value.

```
OneWire oneWire(13); // Pin=13 (we'll not actually use pin13)
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);

void setup(void)  {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // Runtime: 
  //  Change PIN value associated with OneWire 
  //  bus - From now on Pin 4 will be used
  oneWire.begin(4); 

  sensors.begin();
}
```

EDITED to clarify comment from Brahma Fear:

> Are we sure that the library does not modify the state of the GPIO "dummy" pin? Ie, could the pin referenced be in use by something  else? – Brahma Fear

The Constructor for the OneWire class is
    OneWire(uint8_t pin) { begin(pin); }
so a call to "OneWire::begin(pin)" is made and into begin(pin) there is a call to 
    `pinMode(pin, INPUT);`

Note:
   Arduino pins are by default configured as inputs (high-impedance state)

So, you can set, as "dummy", a pin of the board that your app is not going 
to use. If, for example, you have nothing connected to pin D13 (BUILTIN LED on many Arduino board):

```
OneWire oneWire(D13);
```

Or set a PIN you actually use but, in setup(), set it to whatever is needed:

```
OneWire oneWire(D5);
...
setup(){
    pinMode(D5, OUTPUT);
}
```

Please Note:
Depending on the BOARD/Architecture you use (Arduino-AVR, ESP32, ...) some pins may be used for board-specific hardware. For example, PIN 0,1 are used in many Arduino boards as Serial:(RX),(TX)
In sample code i provided in the first place i used PIN=1
This is the same than SET (TX) as an INPUT. Not a clever thing to do.
BUT in setup() there is a call to "Serial.begin(115200);" so PIN 1 is reset to whatever Serial.begin() needs (probably OUTPUT...).

> Another option and is to ADD ONE LINE in the OneWire lib...

The code proposed above is a workaround needed 'cause the OneWire Class Constructor have PIN as a parameter.
This means the code below **does not compiles**:

```
OneWire oneWire(); // NO PIN 
void setup(void)
    {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    oneWire.begin(2); 
    .....
    }
```

You find the Constructor definition into OneWire lib'e header file (...Arduino/libraries/OneWire/OneWire.h - line 72 in the version i have)

If you add there a line where you **Overload the constructor** to accept no parameters:

OneWire() { ; }

than the code above does compiles and everything works ok **with no need for dummy pin**.
If you are going this way, i would strongly recomend to NOT CHANGE the OneWire lib installed in your development computer.
Copy it in a subdir of your project, modify it there and include the modified 
version in the project.
Or fork the gitHub repo and edit the code.

Comment: Hmm.  Excellent idea.  Are we sure that the library does not modify the state of the GPIO "dummy" pin?  Ie, could the pin referenced be in use by something else?

Comment: @Lucabuka, What is really strange to me is that using library e.g. version 2.3.5, it seems present a constructor without input parameters:

`public:
    OneWire() { }
    OneWire(uint8_t pin) { begin(pin); }
    void begin(uint8_t pin);`

But anyhow it still not building.. why?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the simple option is:
You declare a global pointer and use the new operator to create your instance on the heap. Many people discourage this though unless absolutely necessary.
You'll find plenty of discussions about the use of new in Arduino if you care why.

```
SomeClass * pMyInstance; 

void setup(void) {
    pMyInstance = new SomeClass(1);
}
```

Another option would move that particular initialization from setup into loop an more or less treat loop as your global environment.

```
void setup(void) {
}
void loop(void){
   SomeClass myInstance(1);
   while(1){
   // do the loopy stuff in here
   }

}
```

I'm sure there are many better solutions. My C/C++/Arduino is pretty rusty ;)

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks.  Forgot to use 'new' in my example code which was likely causing the created object to be deallocated after setup().  Makes sense and is working now.

Comment: In `setup()` I think you may need to test `pMyInstance` to see if there is an object already assigned to it. I am rusty on Arduino as well so am unsure if `setup()` can be called more than once, for instance reset button pressed or other trigger, and what kind of environment contract for when `setup()` is called, e.g. runtime and application and libraries are reset to a known initial state.